# Angular 4.3 httpclient api request every 30 seconds?

Tags: angular

I already used Anguler4.3 Httpclecnt module to call API. But I want to request get endpoint every 120 seconds. Do you have sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [interval operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval)

```
this.http.get().interval(120000)
```

Comment: @halfer got it.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply wrap your call inside setInterval with 120 seconds as the iteration interval:

```
setInterval( () => {

    // ... your code ..

}, 120000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Observable

```
Observable.interval(120000).subscribe(interationNumber => {
    console.log(iterationNumber);
    //Put your code here
});
```

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 4+ better to use `IntervalObservable` operator, like this:

```
import { IntervalObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
       IntervalObservable.create(1000).subscribe(responce => 
       console.log(response));
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/IntervalObservable.ts